# ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0

Tags: conemu

I was trying to create a shortcut on my Windows desktop to ConEmu64.exe that launches with a script I wrote called "MyStartUpScript.cmd".

In Target field of the Windows shortcut, I have:

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd path/to/MyStartUpScript.cmd
```

However, this does not work. Specifically, it launches a new instance of ConEmu, runs my script, but then it says "ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0"

What is going on?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1061571/make-conemu-close-after-exiting-batch-file#_=_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First. Learn about `cmd.exe` switches. When you run your "startup script" that way you tell `cmd.exe` to execute your script and immediately exit. I doubt it was your intention.

`cmd /?` would give you an answer.

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd cmd.exe /k path/to/MyStartUpScript.cmd
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out exactly what you said before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that open conEmu with admin rights solve the problem (right click -> "run as adminsitrator").

Comment: I found run as admin worked for me too. But I also found this to work: C:\Dropbox\Scripts\Bash\myConEmuScript.cmd -cur_console:n